# Modal-Pop up showing a List of Related Documents filtered by individual List Item in a LVWP

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, query-string

I have an item list called "MyPeople". I have a document list called "MyDocs". I associated documents in "MyDocs" to list items in "MyPeople" via Lookup field. On my Site page, I have a LVWP for "MyPeople". The only column in "MyPeople" is a calculated column with a hyperlink. When pressed, I'd like to invoke a pop-up showing a list view of the "MyDocs" document library filtered by the list item. I want this to work for each individual list item. How can I do this? I only need help getting this form/query/filter to exist. I know how to make the calculated column invoking a pop-up box. Thank you!

**This has been solved. Working script is below. Thanks again to Venkat Konjeti**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">    
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopup(filterValue) {
alert(filterValue)
var pageUrl = "https://MY-REAL-URL.sharepoint.com/MyDocs/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=RelatedPeople&FilterValue1=" + filterValue;  
var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 700, height: 600, title: "My Docs" };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', 
options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirements I understand that you have to open a modal window with list documents associated with the person in the MyPerson list. 
To achieve this you can make following changes.

**Change to the calculated column with hyperlink**

The link should be formatted as follows

```
<a href="javascript:openPopup('" + personname + "')">show my docs</a>
```

**Add JavaScript to open Modal Popup**

You should following script using script editor web part to the MyPeople list view web part page.

`function openPopup(filterValue) {
        var pageUrl = "siteurl/Lists/MyDocs/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MyPeopleFieldLookupName&FilterValue1=filterValue";
        var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 700, height: 600, title: "My Docs" };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    }`

Let me know if any of assumption is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! Going to try this out now, and I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Just to clarify, **personname** should be replaced with 'Title' field in my case. The 'Title' field  in "MyPeople" List contain the list of names. Documents are then associated with each of these names -- is this correct?     =<a href="javascript:openPopup('" + Title + "')">show my docs</a>

Comment: Yes. In order to get the filters, you can few steps. Go to "MyDocs" list and filter your lookup column with one value. It will show the filtered results and from the URL you see what it should be.

Comment: What if I opted to use Text fields with autocomplete jquery script on them  instead of using lookup columns? Would it be the same process? I don't want to use Lookup columns, because they mess things up in Workflows. I think it would be easier to use text fields instead of lookups. Does that make sense?

Comment: For instance, this would be the 'RelatedPeople' Text column in the 'MyDocs' library, referencing the 'MyPeople' list items in the autocomplete script.    
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
                sourceList: "MyPeople",
                sourceColumn: "Title",
                columnName: "RelatedPeople",
                filterType: "Contains",
                ignoreCase: true,
                numChars: 0,
                slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
            });
        });

Comment: You mean instead of lookup field you pass the MyPerson Title value copied to a text column in a MyDocs list. It works for this scenario also. You can design as an auto-complete up to the business case.

Comment: In the 'MyDocs' Library, the text field that is hooked into the autocomplete (which pulls names from the 'MyPeople' list is called 'RelatedPeople'.  What should I be putting down for 'filterValue'? function openPopup(filterValue) {
        var pageUrl = "siteurl/MyDocs/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=RelatedPeople&FilterValue1=filterValue<---what goes here?";
        var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 700, height: 600, title: "My Docs" };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    }

Comment: It's not working -- I think I'm confused on something. Here is the Calculated Field in the 'MyPeople' list:  <a href="javascript:openPopup('"+ Title + "')">show my docs</a>

Comment: Can you check the browser developer window console to see any errors

Comment: I can't even get the pop-up to on on the site page. Can I use a <a href='#' onclick="&"SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage command instead?

Comment: No errors. 1. What's supposed to go in place of these: "FilterValue1=filterValue", or do they stay the way thy are? 2. Which jquery library version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.9 jQuery version. In you case it should be FilterValue1=<<Title value>>

Comment: Should I be writing it just like that? "FilterValue1=<<Title value>>" or like  "FilterValue1=Title"???? Please let me know?

Comment: First test the link what you are using to open popup . Example https://yourtenantdomain.sharepoint.com/Lists/test/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=yourtextfieldname&FilterValue1=TheJDScott

Comment: Still not working -- I've included a screenshot showing you my script in comparison to yours. the image can be found at the top. Thanks!

Comment: Can you inspect the hyperlink generated and get the href attribute value

Comment: It looks normal in the inspector, but when I manually copy the element, I get this...<a href="javascript:openPopup('" +="" Andrew="" +"')"="">show my docs</a>

Comment: I'm getting 'invalid/unexpected token' error, as well

Comment: your tag should be like this when you inspect element browser <a href="javascript:openPopup('Andrew')">show my docs</a>

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got the pop-up to open and the "MyDocs" listview in the pop-up to show and be filtered. The only issue left is that the doc list is empty no matter which name I click on. The 'MyDocs' listview is being filtered by the actual text string "filterValue" -- what should I put in place of "filterValue" in the script?

Comment: I tried replacing FilterValue1=filterValue"; with 'Title', Title, and Title.value, but it only filters the list on that exact text string and not the 'FilterValue1' variable.

Comment: Just for testing can you replace the filtervalue with Andrew in this line ` var pageUrl = "siteurl/Lists/MyDocs/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=RelatedPeople&FilterValue1=Andrew";`

Comment: It worked when I put a static variable in -- I filtered by "siteurl/Lists/MyDocs/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=RelatedPeople&FilterV‌​alue1=Andrew"; and it showed the documents related to Andrew

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59140/discussion-on-answer-by-venkat-konjeti-modal-pop-up-showing-a-list-of-related-do).

Comment: So change to this "siteurl/Lists/MyDocs/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=RelatedPeop‌​le&FilterV‌​alue1=" + filtervalue